# Graphing a complicated equation

Tags: graphing-functions

How do I draw the graph of this equation

$p(\theta^{*} (x))\hat{G} - (1-p(\theta^{*} (x)))(\bar{P} - r(x)) = \check{G}$

Here the $\check{G}$ is a positive constant and is a straight line, but how can I plot the left-hand-side of the equation?

The $x$-axis is just $x$ here. Here $p$ is a function of $\theta$ with $p'(\theta) > 0$, and $p''(\theta) < 0$, $r(0)=0$, $r'(x)>0$. Also $\hat{G}$ and $\bar{P}$ are positive constants.

Also, $\theta$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,1]$.

Maybe I'll need to a software or something to plot it. Any suggestions on how I can use Matlab for this?